# How To Check If Target Variable is different in duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of duplicated values based on text variable.

[image: Duplicated Dataframe]

Now, I want to get all the duplicate rows based on the text and view the ones that have different target labels in a pandas DataFrame. For example, a tweet may say 'Hi, I need help' and the target value is 1, however, the duplicate copy of this tweet may have a target value of 0, therefore, this tweet would be displayed in a pandas dataframe.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `Series.str.find()` is what you are after.  dfTarget['Indexes'] =  df['text'].str.find('I need help')  would make a dataframe with all of the found items in the column text

Comment: `df.groupby("text")['target'].nunique().gt(1)`